# Issue while installing pod

Tags: firebase, cocoa, cocoapods, moya

Added Firebase pod for Cloud Messaging(Push notification)

**pod 'Firebase/Core'**

**pod 'Firebase/Messaging'**

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>     "__T09Alamofire11URLEncodingVAA17ParameterEncodingAAWP", referenced from:
>         __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o
>     "__T09Alamofire12JSONEncodingVN", referenced from:
>         __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o
>     "__T09Alamofire11URLEncodingVN", referenced from:
>         __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o
>     "__T09Alamofire12JSONEncodingVAA17ParameterEncodingAAWP", referenced from:
>         __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o
>     "__T09Alamofire11URLEncodingV7defaultACfgZ", referenced from:
>         __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o
>     "__T09Alamofire12JSONEncodingV7defaultACfgZ", referenced from:
>         __T09App0A3ApiO4task4Moya4TaskOfg in App.o
>   ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am also using Moya. But issue while adding Firebase pods.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs it looks like you miss also the AlamoFire (which can be a dependency of your pods). Try do a `pod deintegrate` and then a `pod install` again and don't forget to open the Workspace and not the project.